# Disable 'Don't Reopen' or 'Reopen' dialog on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, ios-simulator

I've disabled the crash reporter on iOS so I don't get a dialog when the app crashes, but when I next open the app I get the following dialog.

[image]

Does anyone have any idea how to stop this dialog from appearing?

It's causing a problem because I'm calling the simulator via the command line on our build machines and this is causing the job to hang because it never gets to the actual simulator.

Any ideas on how to resolve this would be really useful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I needed to run the following to disable the save state for the emulator

```
defaults write com.apple.iphonesimulator NSQuitAlwaysKeepsWindows -bool false
```

I also ran the following to try and catch any other problems

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode NSQuitAlwaysKeepsWindows -bool false
```

At least, that seems to have worked, it's hard to track as I don't watch the build machine constantly to verify the behaviour...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how disable the dialog, but my next thought was to use Apple Script to programmatically respond to the dialog if you know the dialog will be appearing systematically. Perhaps a solution similar to what red_menace proposes here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2589828?tstart=0